# How to solve - [sendmail: Error during delivery: Reply Code is not valid: ecur ]?

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer, sendmail

I'm trying to develop a basic PHP mail application for my homework/practice purpose. That why I'm working on my local development environment(XAMPP).

My php.ini code:

```
[mail function]
SMTP=mail.example.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = info@example.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

My sendmail.ini code

```
[sendmail]
smtp_server=mail.example.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=info@example.com
auth_password=*********
force_sender=info@example.com
```

My used PHP code for send email:

```
$to      = 'example@gmail.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = array(
    'From' => 'webmaster@example.com',
    'Reply-To' => 'webmaster@example.com',
    'X-Mailer' => 'PHP/' . phpversion()
);

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

The following error occurred while sending the mail from the localhost.

```
sendmail: Error during delivery: Reply Code is not valid: ecur
```

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

What could be the possible solution?

Comment: Since you tagged this question with PHPMailer, you might do better to actually use it, as then you can use SMTP to localhost which will give you much better feedback on such errors.

Comment: @Synchro Thanks for your suggestion. I updated the tag and if you think my question is ok don't forget to give an upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

was enough with go to sendemai.ini and change this

```
smtp_ssl=none
```

And started to work